# Flutter Custom Checkbox setState in dynamic List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list and using my custom checkbox that I design myself to click on the card to indicate done or not done by using the setState to change the variable to true or false

How to make click one checkbox will only check on that card only?

Currently when I click one checkbox will also check all the checkbox

Here is my Dartpad : https://dartpad.dev/f538bee48a18438c25024cbc5eeac14c

My code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TestPageTwo(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestPageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageTwoState createState() => _TestPageTwoState();
}

class _TestPageTwoState extends State<TestPageTwo> {
  bool isComplete = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Task List'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: taskList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              _buildTaskCard(index, taskList[index]),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildTaskCard(int itemIndex, TaskModel task) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
      elevation: 5.0,
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 70,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isComplete = !isComplete;
                    });
                    print(isComplete);
                  },
                  child: isComplete
                      ? Icon(
                          Icons.check_circle_outline_outlined,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          size: 40,
                        )
                      : Icon(
                          Icons.radio_button_unchecked,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          size: 40,
                        ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  task.taskTitle,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  task.taskCategory,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                ),
                dense: true,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskModel {
  final String taskId,
      taskStatus,
      taskTitle,
      taskCategory;

  TaskModel(
      {this.taskId,
      this.taskStatus,
      this.taskTitle,
      this.taskCategory});
}

List<TaskModel> taskList = [
  TaskModel(
      taskId: 'task00001',
      taskStatus: 'Incomplete',
      taskTitle: 'Task 00001',
      taskCategory: 'A0001'),
  TaskModel(
      taskId: 'task00002',
      taskStatus: 'Completed',
      taskTitle: 'Task 00002',
      taskCategory: 'A0002'),
  TaskModel(
      taskId: 'task00003',
      taskStatus: 'Incomplete',
      taskTitle: 'Task 00003',
      taskCategory: 'A0003',),
  TaskModel(
      taskId: 'task00004',
      taskStatus: 'Incomplete',
      taskTitle: 'Task 00004',
      taskCategory: 'A0004',),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TestPageTwo(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestPageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageTwoState createState() => _TestPageTwoState();
}

class _TestPageTwoState extends State<TestPageTwo> {
  bool isComplete = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Task List'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: taskList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              _buildTaskCard(index, taskList[index]),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildTaskCard(int itemIndex, TaskModel task) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
      elevation: 5.0,
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 70,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      task.taskStatus = !task.taskStatus;
                    });
                    print(isComplete);
                  },
                  child: task.taskStatus
                      ? Icon(
                          Icons.check_circle_outline_outlined,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          size: 40,
                        )
                      : Icon(
                          Icons.radio_button_unchecked,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          size: 40,
                        ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  task.taskTitle,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  task.taskCategory,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                ),
                dense: true,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskModel {
  final String taskId,
      taskTitle,
      taskCategory;
  bool taskStatus = false;


  TaskModel(
      {this.taskId,
      this.taskStatus,
      this.taskTitle,
      this.taskCategory});
}

List<TaskModel> taskList = [
  TaskModel(
      taskId: 'task00001',
      taskStatus: false,
      taskTitle: 'Task 00001',
      taskCategory: 'A0001'),
  TaskModel(
      taskId: 'task00002',
      taskStatus: true,
      taskTitle: 'Task 00002',
      taskCategory: 'A0002'),
  TaskModel(
      taskId: 'task00003',
      taskStatus: false,
      taskTitle: 'Task 00003',
      taskCategory: 'A0003',),
  TaskModel(
      taskId: 'task00004',
      taskStatus: false,
      taskTitle: 'Task 00004',
      taskCategory: 'A0004',),
];
```